How to visualize adversarial attacks correctly? Color changes visible despite unnormalization and clipping
I'm trying to visualize adversarial examples generated with FGSM using torchattacks. Despite unnormalizing and clipping the images, I still notice visible color changes. Here is a simplified version of my code:

import numpy as np
import torch
from torchvision import models, transforms, datasets
from PIL import Image
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torchattacks


imagenet_val_path = r'C:\datasets\imagenet\val'

val_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(imagenet_val_path, transform=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
]))


device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = models.resnet50(weights=models.ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1)
model = model.to(device)
model.eval()



# Load image 751 and label from dataset
image, label = val_dataset[750]
input_batch = image.unsqueeze(0)

input_batch = input_batch.to(device)
labels = torch.tensor([label]).to(device)

#predictions for the clean image
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(input_batch)
probabilities = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output[0], dim=0)
top5_prob_clean, top5_catid_clean = torch.topk(probabilities, 5)


attack = torchattacks.FGSM(model, eps=8/255)
adv_images = attack(input_batch, labels)

#predictions on the adversarial examples
with torch.no_grad():
    output_adv = model(adv_images)
probabilities_adv = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output_adv[0], dim=0)
top5_prob_adv, top5_catid_adv = torch.topk(probabilities_adv, 5)

#ImageNet class labels
LABELS_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anishathalye/imagenet-simple-labels/master/imagenet-simple-labels.json"
labels_list = requests.get(LABELS_URL).json()

# Unnormalization parameters
mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

def unnormalize(img_tensor, mean, std):

    img_tensor = img_tensor.permute(1, 2, 0).cpu().numpy()
    # Unnormalize
    img_tensor = img_tensor * std + mean
    # Clip to [0,1]
    img_tensor = np.clip(img_tensor, 0, 1)
    # back to [0,255]
    img_tensor = (img_tensor * 255).astype("uint8")
    return img_tensor

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))


plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
clean_image = unnormalize(image, mean, std)
plt.imshow(clean_image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Clean Image')


plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.barh(range(5), top5_prob_clean.cpu().numpy())
plt.yticks(range(5), [labels_list[top5_catid_clean[i]] for i in range(5)])
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel('Probability')
plt.title('Top 5 (Clean Image)')


plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
adv_image = unnormalize(adv_images.squeeze(), mean, std)
plt.imshow(adv_image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Adversarial Image')


plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.barh(range(5), top5_prob_adv.cpu().numpy())
plt.yticks(range(5), [labels_list[top5_catid_adv[i]] for i in range(5)])
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel('Probability')
plt.title('Top 5  (Adversarial Image)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

print("Top 5 Predictions for the Clean Image:")
for i in range(top5_prob_clean.size(0)):
    print(f"{labels_list[top5_catid_clean[i]]}: {top5_prob_clean[i].item()}")

print("\nTop 5 Predictions for the Adversarial Image:")
for i in range(top5_prob_adv.size(0)):
    print(f"{labels_list[top5_catid_adv[i]]}: {top5_prob_adv[i].item()}")


The output looks like the following, which is shows obvious difference between clean and FGSM. Commenting unnormalization line (img_tensor = img_tensor * std + mean), makes them look similar but the colors are not nice looking. What is the exact issue? And how to fix it?
thanks!

